# Muliple instances of modelform

Tags: django, view, modelform

I have a list in my template. For each item in the list, I have a {{ modelform }} that contains a checkbox. I can check the box and it updates as should. The problem is that when I check the box for one item and submit, it submits for all of the checkboxes because they are the same in each instance. Is there a way to set up a unique checkbox instance for each item in the list?

Current each modelform checkbox renders the same like this:

```
<input name="is_solution" type="checkbox" class="is_solution" id="is_solution">
```

I also tried using

```
test = request.POST.get('checkbox')
```

and

```
test = request.POST.get('checkbox')
```

thinking that using this I might be able to post an update in my view. I think I am going about this all wrong and I am lost. Essentially, I would like to have a checkbox on a list much like here on stackexchange where you can confirm an answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use form's prefix in the view like (just something unique for each form object):

```
def foo(request, ...):
    objs = Model.objects.filter(...)
    forms = []
    for i, obj in enumerate(objs):
        form = ModelForm(instance=obj, prefix=str(i))
        forms.append(form)
    ...
```

This will make sure each form has unique identifier, hence you will be able to submit a specific form.

And you can render the forms like usual in the template:

```
<form ...>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for form in forms %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```